# Calling SharePoint with HttpClient PostAsync() results into forbidden response

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpclient, httpresponse

I am trying to send HttpClient PostAsync() request to company's internal sharepoint site but its returning response with forbidden error. I have all necessary access permission for site to load and have also passed required headers to the HttpClient object.

Here is code snippet.

```
HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient (new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true });

client.BaseAddress = new Uri (string.Format (API_URL, p_siteNumber));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add (new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue (@"application/atom+xml"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation ("Accept-Language", "en-US, en;q=0.8, hi;q=0.6");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation ("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation ("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");

HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync (urlHttpPost, new StringContent (string.Empty));

string response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't really help much based on what little you've given us. Either you're missing a header or some sort of cookie or post value that the server is expecting. I suggest using software such as Fiddler to sniff out a valid request and apply that to your code.

Comment: If you do the same request with the same headers and content from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en do you get the same result?

Comment: What URL did you use? What did you try to do? You can't access a library or list if your account doesn't have permission to use them. Have you tried using the [Client Object Model](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) ? Start with it to eliminate request problems, eg invalid URLs or bad headers

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem I wanted to send the file and some string contents with it.

so below code helped me!!

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "CBS Brightcove API Service");
            string authorization = GenerateBase64();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorization);


            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text);

                //Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
                var stringContent = new StringContent(InstancePropertyObject);
                stringContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
                stringContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                stringContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"instance\"");
                content.Add(stringContent, "instance");

                var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(filecontent);
                fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = fileName
                };
                content.Add(fileContent);

                var result = client.PostAsync(targetURL, content).Result; 
            }
        }
```